# how do I import json generated by javascript into Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to get rid of the newline character that separates objects in a json file so that I can import properly into mongodb without having the objects in an array.  What do I use in javascript to do this?  I need my data in this format so that I can import:

{ name: "Widget 1", desc: "This is Widget 1" }
{ name: "Widget 2", desc: "This is Widget 2" }

Comment: Thanks for the resource.  I'll try that npm package and will post my progress shortly.  I'm hopeful that this will indeed work.

Comment: if you just need a "new-line" separated string of objects, do this: `var string = arrayOfObjects.join('\n')`

Comment: Actually I fixed it using JSON.stringify(object)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you dont have to convert the file to an array, `mongoimport` expects a "json-line" format like you already have.

This format is very good for performance, because you don't have to load it at once, instead mongo will take line by line. So imagine a billion lines, if you convert it to an array, it will cost memory...

This way its just a linear time operation, the lines gets streamed into the db.

look here:

http://zaiste.net/2012/08/importing_json_into_mongodb/

---

However, if you think you need to do the conversion, just do it like this:

```
fs.readFile('my.json', function(e, text) {
   var arrayLikeString = "[" + text.split('\n').join(',') + "]";
   var array = JSON.parse(arrayLikeString);
})
```

---

To import an array of objects use this command:

```
mongoimport --db <db-name> --collection <coll-name> --type json --jsonArray --file seed.json
```

note the option: **--jsonArray**

---

### Finally:

Take a look at this npm package, it looks very promisingly:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonlines

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not wanting it in an array.  I need to get my data into the format you are talking about and I don't know how.  Using JavaScript I'm printing out the objects one by one each on a new line without being separated by commas but mongoimport isn't accepting this format.  Using an array of objects is too slow for me.

Comment: You can also import an array of objects, note my edits

Comment: I don't want to import an array of objects.  I'm looking to import each object themselves without them being in an array.